# How do I match a pattern with alphabets AND numbers, but not if it contains only alphabets?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use regex that checks a string for alphabets and numbers, but it shouldn't match if the string contains only alphabets. This is for a javascript code. Should lookahead be used?

Should match:
1234567
a1b2c3d4e5
1a2b3c4d5e

Should not match:
abcdefg

**EDIT:** Thanks to @balsick this question has been answered. Here's the regex to be used - (([a-zA-Z0-9]+\d+[a-zA-Z0-9]*)|(\d+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\d*))+

I do have a follow-up question: can a length constraint be added to this regex? For example: I want to match only strings that are 10-20 alphabets/digits.

Comment: *Stack Overflow Wouldn't Be Very Welcoming*. Show your attempts and tag a language or tool.

Comment: This is a good question and perfect for SO. I don't understand the down votes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assert the start of the string `^`, use a non capturing group `(?:` with an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either a digit `\d` or `|` one or more characters followed by a digit `[a-z]+\d`. This makes sure that you have at least 1 digit and that you could also start with characters.

Then for the last part of the regex you could match zero or more digits and characters `[a-z\d]*` until the end of the string `$`.

To match upper and lowercase characters you could use `[a-z]` with the case insensitive flag `/i`

[`^(?:\d|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/pDjbEx/1)

```js
let pattern = /^(?:\d|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*$/i;
const strings = [
  "a1b2c3d4e5",
  "1a2b3c4d5e",
  "abcdefg",
  "1234567"
];
strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s));
});
```

If you want to make sure that your match contains 10 - 20 alphanumeric characters you could use a positive lookahead:

[`^(?=[a-z\d]*\d)[a-z\d]{10,20}$`](https://regex101.com/r/OtVfdG/1)

```js
let pattern = /^(?=[a-z\d]*\d)[a-z\d]{10,20}$/i;
const strings = [
  "a1b2c3d4e5",
  "1a2b3c4d5e",
  "1234567",
  "abcdefg",
  "1234567",
  "12112121121fffdfdfdfdfdfdfd",
  "fdfddfdfdffdfdf5ffrtgr54f345f453f3ff"
];
strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
((\w+\d+\w*)|(\d+\w+\d*))+
```

\w looks for alphabetic

\d looks for digits

+ means at least one

* means zero or more

| is the or operator

### EDIT (Improvement)

I have found a better solution for your primary question. It is shorter and faster than the solution of @balsick and it won't catch the `_` character:

```
([a-zA-Z]*\d[a-zA-Z]*)+
```

Your wish to limit the length of strings is hard to conquer with regex. There are options to limit the number of matches. For example with:

`a{5}`, `a{2,}` exactly five, two or more

`a{1,3}`    between one & three

But this won't work with the upper regex, because each single submatch will be either

- one or more letters in combination with a number like: *aa1*,
- a number in combination with one or more letters like: *1aaa*,
- one or more letters in combination with a number and one or more letter like: *a1aa*
- or a single number like: *1*

If you have an match like `a1b2c3d4e5` it consists out of these submatches: `a1b` `2c` `3d` `4e` `5`

Although the match consists out of 10 characters, using the quantifier `{10,20}` instead of the last plus sign won't work, because the real number of submatches would be 5 and not 10.

I think you have to use the upper regex and after that check the length of each match programatically afterwords.

Pseudo code:

```
foreach (var match in matches) {
    if (match.Value.length < 21 && match.Value.length > 9) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Or if you have the possibility to use Linq you could do something like this:

```
var filteredMatches = matches.Filter(match => match.Value.length < 21 && match.Value.length > 9)
```

Comment: It's not fully correct because you are considering also `_`. `(([a-zA-Z0-9]+\d+[a-zA-Z0-9]*)|(\d+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\d*))+` is more correct

Comment: thanks @balsick! that works like a charm. Is there a way to add a length constraint to the regex you have? For example: i want to match those strings that are between 10-20 alphabets/digits only.

Comment: @anil-premkumar I have updated my answer. I hope this will help you.

Comment: I just realized my comment was wrong :) there was a 0-9 in the square brackets that shouldn't be there. moreover, the regex can be simplified like this  `(([a-zA-Z]+\d+)|(\d+[a-zA-Z]+))+`

Answer (score 0):

Answer updated with input from @balsick

Using lookahead Regex:

```
^(?=[A-Za-z\d]*\d)[A-Za-z\d]*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xo4hGw/2/)

Comment: this actually doesn't work as you expect because it also matches strings like _____3. Maybe you meant `^(?=[A-Za-z\d]*\d)[A-Za-z\d]*$`

Comment: Lookaheads and lookbehinds are expensive in time and not supported by every programming language

Comment: @balsick, I agree. Please post your regex as answer, I'll delete mine.